# Getting error while start mysql in xamp

Tags: windows, mysql, xampp

I am getting an error when try to start mysql in xamp

```
11:31:58 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
11:32:03 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
11:32:03 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:32:03 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:32:03 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:32:03 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:32:03 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:32:03 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
11:32:03 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

I have changed the apache port to 8081.After that apache working fine.And tried to change mysql port  but it is not working.

Comment: Why the need to change the MySQL port? Any production site will use the defaults...

Comment: No mysql port is running in deafult.

Comment: If you do a `netstat -a` (I think) in `cmd` then it will tell you what's listening on MySQL port. This will tell you if it's a port problem.

Comment: no port is showing for mysql